# Why does forkJoin not complete for an array of new Observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, switchmap

I'm trying to use forkjoin on some asynchronous tasks but for some reason I don't get the emission on forkjoin.

See stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-form-validation-yrstmk?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts

```js
import { forkJoin, Observable, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  db: ReplaySubject<IDBDatabase> = new ReplaySubject(1);

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('init!');

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('db init!');
      this.db.next(null);
    }, 2000);

    const test = [this.create(null), this.create(null), this.create(null)];
    forkJoin(test).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('forkjoined!');
    });
  }

  create(variable: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.db.pipe(
      switchMap(
        () =>
          new Observable<any>(observer => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              console.log('next!');
              observer.next(variable);
              observer.complete();
            }, 1000);
          })
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: most likely your one of your observables does not complete. if that's the case you should use `combineLatest` instead of `forkJoin`.

Comment: @Stavm yep you're correct. Because I switchMap on the ReplaySubject, and ReplaySubject doesn't complete.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the outer observable is a `ReplaySubject` which will not complete.

I simply added `take(1)` to my pipe.

```js
  create(variable: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.db.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap(
        () =>
          new Observable<any>(observer => {
            console.log('next!');
            observer.next(variable);
            observer.complete();
          })
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated your stackblitz.: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-form-validation-adupub?file=src/app/app.component.ts

You have to:

- Add a variable to access it on subscribe(HERE).
- Return a value in the next.

Check de diffs:
Your code:

```
// line 30
forkJoin(test).subscribe(() => {
   console.log('forkjoined!');
});
//line 42
switchMap(
        () =>
          new Observable<any>(observer => {
            console.log('next!');
            observer.next(variable);
            observer.complete();
          })
      )
```

My code:

```
//line 30
forkJoin(test).subscribe((data) => {
   console.log('forkjoined!',data);
});
//Line 42
switchMap(
        () =>
          new Observable<any>(observer => {
            console.log('next!');
            observer.next("variable");
            observer.complete();
          })
      )
```

[image]